# Getting the amount of available lines in a terminal

Tags: python, terminal

How can the amount of available lines in a terminal be found?

Preferably in a cross-platform manner but any suggestions (even OS-specific) are welcome.

The height and length of a terminal can be found using the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#querying-the-size-of-a-terminal) module however this does not take into account the amount of lines that may already have been used.

To clarify things here is an example:

[image]

In this example the height of the terminal here is 33 however since 3 lines have been used, only 30 lines are available.

Comment: Interesting question. Probably OS specific. Perhaps you could add the `cmd` tag.

Comment: @JohnColeman  I would like it to be cross platform ideally but if you think I should I will.

Comment: I'm not certain this is possible unless you keep track of all output to the console manually

Comment: I doubt that a cross-platform solution is possible (though if you have OS - specific solutions then you could dynamically decide on which one to use).

Comment: @bendl Since Windows (or other OS) knows where to print next, the relevant information is *somewhere* -- though you might have to dig deep to find it.

Comment: There is a `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` function in the Windows API. Don't know if there is anything simpler than that.

Comment: like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440694-determine-size-of-console-window-on-windows/) ?

Comment: This is an example of using that API function from Python: https://www.burgaud.com/bring-colors-to-the-windows-console-with-python/

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Determining by that screen shot, you are on Windows

This is from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440694-determine-size-of-console-window-on-windows/

```
from ctypes import windll, create_string_buffer

# stdin handle is -10
# stdout handle is -11
# stderr handle is -12

h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-12)
csbi = create_string_buffer(22)
res = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, csbi)

if res:
    import struct
    (bufx, bufy, curx, cury, wattr,
     left, top, right, bottom, maxx, maxy) = struct.unpack("hhhhHhhhhhh", csbi.raw)
    sizex = right - left + 1
    sizey = bottom - top + 1
else:
    sizex, sizey = 80, 25 # can't determine actual size - return default values

print sizex, sizey, curx, cury
```

That will give you screen size, and the cursor position.

`cury` is the line, so you can calculate the number of lines left.

However, you may want to re-check the console window size as you progress, as the user may resize the window at any time.

Comment: doesn't curx and cury allow right away for the calculation OP wants?

Comment: @progmatico ... oh that is right... well spotted. cury will give you the line. Answer updated. Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just one problem.  I am running Python 3 (and I don't know Python 2).  If I add the `()` to print statement I get the error:`NameError: name 'curx' is not defined`.

Comment: The only thing to change is ( ) for the print statement on the last line. The problem error you are getting is because you are running it on an IDE and not an actual console... try running in an actual console.

Comment: **Just what I was after thank you**.  However just a note.  It counts text and  not new lines, so if I used 30 new lines it would still say 33 are available, for this reason I will wait a day or so until I accept this answer. In any case this is worthy of an up-vote.  Thank you once again for the quick reply.

Comment: @Simon `sizey - cury` is giving me a consistent "lines left" up to the point you have used more lines than available; which means `cury > sizey`, you are using the console buffer and the console window starts scrolling. Using Python3 on Win10, tested on 3 machines consistently.... not sure why you get different results.

Answer (score 4):

To determine the terminal size (for any OS platform) -

```
import os
size = os.get_terminal_size() 
print(size)
```

The output generated will be : `os.terminal_size(columns=80, lines=24)`
Here columns is the width of the terminal window and lines is the height (80 and 24 is just the reference value). 
You can use these as `print("-"*size.columns)` or anything else. I hope this helps!

Comment: This way you can get the terminal size but not the available lines in a terminal even if we have the number of total lines in a terminal we still doesn't have the record of lines used in a terminal. Your approach might help if someone decides to keep track of the number of lines printed already on the terminal by increasing a counter every time someone prints a `'\n'`.